# Getting error on every newly created project

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever I create a new project in Eclipse for some Android application it gives me a red cross sign and on compiling shows following errors:

```
error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\..\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.
```

On Googling I found that by cleaning the project we can remove this error but it is not working in my case.

Earlier I was able to create Project in Eclipse. All this problem started after installing some Google APIs but I guess they are not cause of problem, something else is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be an issue with a command path?
SDK doesnt like being installed in dirs with long names like "Program Files\Google\Android..."

If that`s the case, you`ll need to adjust path appropriately (C:\Progra~2... or smth like this)

( check http://ideanotion.net/android-sdk-invalid-command-line-parameter-files-error/ or Google )

Comment: I don't think that's the case.My installation path is C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk . I don't think it's too long,is it?

Comment: I got similar problem when "Program Files" was in full, but after I changed it to "PROGRA~2" glitch disappeared