# Getting error on every newly created Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting these two errors every time I run any existing project or any newly created project. I tried to clean the projects but was unsuccessful. Errors are:

> Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xx\workspace\gui_1\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist
>
> Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.

Can anyone help me remove these errors? Yesterday everything was working fine but after installing some google APIs it started showing these errors in every project in Eclipse.

Comment: Is there none who can help me ?

Comment: Your question isn't related to any of the these tags which you had added: `eclipse-plugin`, `android-emulator`, `android-manifest`. Please only add tags which are strictly relevant to the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error on every newly created project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866071/getting-error-on-every-newly-created-project)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.anddev.org/sdk-adt-emulator-problems-f16/unparsed-aapt-errors-check-the-console-for-output-t12615.html) link which basically says clean your project (Project > Clean menu).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had saved a pdf file into the drawable folder of my project in Eclipse. The error went away when I removed it. It **was** an accident, but is there somewhere you can put documentation into an Eclipse Project